# Change application.yaml in Springboot to return dates as longs instead of timestamps

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

We have a Springboot Project, our production application class contain the following annotation: @EnableWebMvc(), thus a call to an end-point returns the following. Note that dates are returned as **long** values.

```
{
 "expirationDate": 1597291200000,
 "dateOfBirth": 271828800000 
}
```

However, in our development branch in the application class we **removed** that annotation and the bellow response is obtained after calling the same end-point. Note that now dates are returned as **timestamps**. How could we change our application.yaml in order to receive the dates as long without having the @EnableWebMvc() annotation. For us the best solution would be in the application.yaml, but any other suggestion is welcomed.

```
{
  "expirationDate": "2020-08-13T04:00:00.000+0000",
  "dateOfBirth": "1978-08-13T04:00:00.000+0000"
}
```

Comment: You say double multiple times but do you mean long?

Comment: Can you show your controller please for this endpoint?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, thank you, I missed that, I did meant long. We are sure that the issue is because of the annotation, as soon as we add it to development the error gets fixed. However, returned data is from a source we have no control over. In the post I added the controller. @Jason

Comment: Update the main post with the **controller** that is handling the request.

Comment: That is how you're calling it from the client. I need to see how the server is generating that response. I need the **controller** in the MVC pattern.

Comment: @Jason let me know if that helps, updated accordingly.

Comment: Updated, and it is possible through properties which is nice, but it is global. Tested it locally.

Comment: @Jason we want it to be global, all our end-points need to return the long format. We are using application.yaml instead of properties file. Any idea how to work it for yaml?

Comment: Updated answer with YAML.

Comment: With YAML think of every . as a new object so spring.jackson.serialization are individual objects; spring: jackson: serialization: WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS: true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using the `JsonFormat` annotation provided by Jackson. In your respective Entity class that you're returning as a response annotate the fields using JsonFormat and provide the shape annotation Shape.NUMBER.

```java
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER)
        final ZonedDateTime expirationDate;

        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER)
        final ZonedDateTime dateOfBirth;
```

This is also possible to achieve globally through the properties file.

Properties

```
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS = true
```

YAML

```yaml
spring:
  jackson:
    serialization:
      WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS: true
```